# Join 2 tables return single row for each related data

Tags: mysql

I am trying to join two tables with distinct photo url but I'm not able to do so. I don't know whether it is possible or not.

My tables appear similar to the examples below and I want to join them.

```sql
+-------------------+     +----------------------------+
|       table1      |     |           table2           |
+----+------+-------+     +----+-----------+-----------+
| id | name | place |     | id | photo_url | table1_id |
+----+------+-------+     +----+-----------+-----------+
|  1 | abc  | xyz   |     |  1 | link1     |         1 |
|  2 | def  | jiu   |     |  2 | link2     |         1 |
|  3 | efw  | jlo   |     |  3 | link3     |         3 |
+----+------+-------+     |  4 | link4     |         2 |
                          +----+-----------+-----------+
```

```sql
+-------------------------------+
|          joined_tbl           |
+----+------+-------+-----------+
| id | name | place | photo_url |
+----+------+-------+-----------+
|  1 | abc  | xyz   | link1     |
|  2 | def  | jiu   | link3     |
|  3 | efw  | jlo   | link4     |
+----+------+-------+-----------+
```

I am new to MySQL and still learning it. I am stuck here, and I appreciate any solutions.

Comment: Which tables are you trying to join? The first two?

Comment: Why link1 and not link2 for table1id as 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT t1.*,
  t2.photo_url
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2
  ON (t1.id = t2.table1_id)
JOIN (
  SELECT min(id) AS id,
    table1_id
  FROM table2
  GROUP BY table1_id
) t3 ON (t2.id = t3.id
   AND t2.table1_id = t3.table1_id)
```

Self `JOIN` for `table2` is to pick only photo per `table1_id`.

---

## [➜ SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1f328/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like:

```
SELECT table1.id,
  table1.name,
  table1.place,
  table2.photo_url
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
  ON table1.id = table2.table1_id;
```

I basically selected the desired fields from your to tables based on the `id` criteria.

You can check MySQL tutorial here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

Depends how you define which value of `photo_url` you want.

Assuming just the `MIN` one:-

```
SELECT table1.id,
  table1.name,
  table1.place,
  MIN(table2.photourl)
FROM table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2
  ON table1.id = table2.table1_id
GROUP BY table1.id,
  table1.name,
  table1.place
```

If you do not care which one (although this works in MySQL, it is dodgy SQL):-

```
SELECT table1.id,
  table1.name,
  table1.place,
  table2.photo_url
FROM table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2
  ON table1.id = table2.table1_id
GROUP BY table1.id,
  table1.name,
  table1.place
```

If you want something a bit more complicated then you will probably need to use a sub-query to get the chosen `photo_url` for each `table1_id`, and then `JOIN` that sub query to `table1`.